# Does maven import option in intelliJ imports jars from remote repositories as well

Tags: java, maven, svn, intellij-idea

Hi I am trying to build maven project using intelliJ. 
I wanted to know what the maven import option does?

Apart from importing files from local repository and remote maven repository, does it imports/ updates files from SVN repository (which I am using).

So do I need to checkout the code from repository everytime or import option does this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maven import functionality in IntelliJ works as follows:

> If you want to use an existing Maven project, you can import it directly by opening its pom.xml file. When a Maven project is imported, it maps to an IntelliJ IDEA module with the name, which is equal to the Maven project's artifactId. Dependencies between the Maven projects map to the dependencies of IntelliJ IDEA modules from the libraries and other modules. IntelliJ IDEA analyzes the pom.xml file and automatically downloads the necessary dependencies.

It will not checkout code from your SVN repository. Maven is a build tool that helps manage dependencies that your package may have, while SVN is a version control system that is meant to track changes you make to code.

Comment: i wanted to know, in case the code gets updated in the repository, does the import option has ability to get the latest code or it will only deal with the code that has been imported by the IDE before itself (or imported using pom.xml file)

Comment: I don't think the import will pull the newest version of the same jar in a repository. You'd need to run the "install" maven option on the project that uses the dependency to download the newest version.